# What does BAG at the beginning of KLM Royal Dutch Airlines' Customer and Product Record mean?

Tags: airlines, terminology, klm

As in:

> --- BAG ---
>  CUSTOMER AND PRODUCT RECORD
>    1 LASTNAME/FIRSTNAME ...

Does it mean something like Beginning of Document?

I think that they are using standardized coding for this information; an outsider to the industry may speculate that some of the information in this record may be initially transferred to the airline from the travel agency in this or similar format.

Here is a scan of the item, with personal information redacted:

[image]

Comment: Which airline(s)?

Comment: KLM, but I think that a standardized coding system is probably used for this.

Comment: Do you have a photo, or link or similar?

Comment: Hey, I actually asked KLM and even they're not sure what  you're talking about -what document is this on? Do you have a link to a webpage, or a photo where you saw it?

Comment: @MarkMayo I have just added a scanned copy of the document. Thanks for having asked KLM about it, I really appreciate it.

Comment: The printout appears to be for a ticket issued by Travelocity on behalf of KLM, not KLM directly.  If it was KLM, it would almost certainly be using Amadeus codes, but your printout doesn't match: http://www.amadeus.com/bg/documents/aco/bg/basic-qrg.pdf

Comment: Is this a group reservation?

Comment: @MeNoTalk It is not a group reservation; it is the individual reservation I got on Travelocity.com. The document was printed out by airline staff at the airport.

Comment: Did you print this at EDI or AMS?

Comment: @MeNoTalk At EDI.

Comment: Ok, I guess BAG stands for the name of the handling company for KLM in EDI, British Airports Group or something like that. Not sure currently, I will post an answer once I confirm.

Comment: I've tweeted KLM's social media person and after they saw the picture, they're going to investigate for us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Klm provided the answer through their [twitter channel](https://twitter.com/KLM/status/525682331278123008):
"

> 'BAG' stands for 'Customer has baggage on his journey' :-) Have a nice weekend!

Comment: I think the guy who replied made this answer on the spot.. I do not think it means a passenger has a luggage.. where is the tag number? come on.. he just wanted to get rid of you.. I said so because in the printout the OP posted it says in the luggage allowance line (8 and 9) that it is not used... if I read that correctly.

Comment: All that work messaging them and you nick my answer? ;)